# How to put a scene in a scene - Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am coming from HTML and javascript development, and in HTML, we have the `iframe` tag. I was wondering if I could put a scene in a SKNode the same way that the `iframe` works. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: SKScene *is* an SKNode, so you can layer them as such. But as WW said, they will not keep track of things like .update and such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a scene to a scene(or to another node), but in that case a scene added as a child will act as an ordinary `SKNode`. So, in short, what you are trying makes no sense because the `update:` method of a child scene will not fire.

It is actually meant to have only one scene per `SKView` (an `SKView` has only one `scene` property). You can have multiple `SKView` instances though, but that is another topic, and if you go that way, and run into some issues, feel free to post a new question.